# JobScheduler vs AlarmManager - (Android)

Tags: android

Tengo la siguiente duda sobre el funcionamiento de JobScheduler:

Estoy creando un ejemplo para replicar el funcionamiento del AlarmManager en  JobScheduler, pero el ejemplo del JobScheduler no se ejecuta después de los 15 días como un AlarmManager. ¿Es posible ejecutar una tarea cada 15 días (ó x días) utilizando JobScheduler como en un AlarmManager?

```
// 15 días
private static final int PERIOD_MS = 15 * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

AlarmManager

```
 Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, BackgroundIntentService.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 1,  newIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

 AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + PERIOD_MS, PERIOD_MS,pendingIntent);
```

JobScheduler

```
    ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context,   BackgroundJobService.class);
    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent);
    //builder.setPeriodic(PERIOD_MS);
    builder.setMinimumLatency(PERIOD_MS);
    builder.setOverrideDeadline(PERIOD_MS);
    JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

De antemano gracias...

Saludos.

Comment: esto te podría servir... <https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/recurring-work?hl=es-419> Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede realizar lo mismo que un `AlarmManager` debes definir 15 días en millisegundos que corresponden a 15 días como la latencía que tendrá tu tarea:

```
 private static final int PERIOD_MS = 15 * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
 ...
 ...
 ...
 builder.setMinimumLatency(PERIOD_MS );
```

de esta forma cada 15 días se llamaría `onStartJob()` de `BackgroundJobService`